# Wicket sharing data across multiple users

Tags: session, wicket

I have a wicket application and it is up and running. The issues is, I have a modal window to edit some user data. When the edit window is open from another user and their sesssion, and then at the same time I open the edit modal window for my own session, the edit window is populated from the window that was opened from the other user, with data that has nothing to do with the data I was editing.

What is happening here? And how do I fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had a static variable I forgot to change -_-   Glad I fixed it. That was scary.